# lua reading chinese character

Tags: lua

I have the following xml that I would like to read:

1. chinese xml - https://news.google.com/news/popular?ned=cn&topic=po&output=rss
2. korean xml - http://www.voanews.com/templates/Articles.rss?sectionPath=/korean/news

Currently, I try to use a luaxml to parse in the xml which contain the chinese character. However, when I print out using the console, the result is that the chinese character cannot be printed correctly and show as a garbage character.

I would like to ask if there is anyway to parse a chinese or korean character into lua table?

Comment: Does your console support Chinese characters?

Comment: Managed to solve it. Turn out that the console, I need to set the unicode to 65001. However, when I tried to read in the xml into table and output it back to xml, it could not display chinese character. Instead of chinese character, it displayed a series of "&#228;&#184;&#173;&#231;&#190;&#142;". Any method that can display the chinese character?

Comment: Those are XML escape codes. Any *application* working with XML should know how to decode those code. If you open the XML in your browser, does it display correctly?

Comment: @robin when I open in the browser, it gives this output" å¤äº¤é¨ï¼ä¸­æ¹å¯¹é»å²©å²ä¸»æå·åååå²åæ³çä¾æ® - æ­å·ç½"

Comment: Interesting. You could see if it looks good if you select another encoding in the browser. Otherwise, I don't know what you could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to convert the "ä¸­ç¾Ž" into chinese character. 
I would need to do one additional step which has to convert all the the series of string by using this method from this link, http://forum.luahub.com/index.php?topic=3617.msg8595#msg8595 before saving into xml format.

```
string.gsub(l,"&#([0-9]+);", function(c) return string.char(tonumber(c)) end)
```

I would like to ask for LuaXML, I have come across this method xml.registerCode(decoded,encoded)

Under that method, it says that

```
registers a custom code for the conversion between non-standard characters and XML character entities
```

What do they mean by non-standard characters and how do I use it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Lua is the issue here.  The raw data the remote site sends is encoded using UTF-8, and Lua does no special interpretation of that—which means it should be preserved perfectly if you just (1) read from the remote site, and (2) save the read data to a file.  The data in the file will contain CJK characters encoded in UTF-8, just like the remote site sent back.

If you're getting funny results like you mention, the fault probably lies either with the library you're using to read from the remote site, or perhaps simply with the way your console displays the results when you output to it.

Comment: So far I tried is to read in from the website, then I output in a text file and from text file and output back to XML. When I take a look at the text then I have saved, it is able to store chinese character, however when I read the text and save it back to xml, the chinese character cannot be displayed and chinese character is substituted with a series of quote which I mentioned earlier.

Comment: When you say "read the text and save it back to xml" what exactly are you doing?  [the text was _already_ in xml form when you fetched it from the website, so ...]  You need to give some more detail about your code...